# directx tutorials c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi, directx-9

im searching for full directx tutorials i found directxtutorial.com but it only gave me the basic. couldn't find others that were full tutorials.
have you find any or know any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you mean Direct3D, in which case you can find some good stuff over at the MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416804%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are some good ones here:

http://www.toymaker.info/Games/index.html