# how did you learn directx 9?

Tags: c++, winapi, directx-9

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Good books or tutorials for beginning Direct X with c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451973/good-books-or-tutorials-for-beginning-direct-x-with-c)
>   [directx tutorials c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792817/directx-tutorials-c)

what tutorials did you use to learn directx 9 or books.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started with Frank D. Luna's book:

[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Game-Programming-Direct-9-0c/dp/1598220160/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1598220160)

and then coded myself into all sorts of trouble until I got things working.

Answer (score 0):

The DirectX SDK installs a sample browser with alot of great examples on how to use DirectX.